# Bower failing to install Polymer/paper-elements

Tags: polymer, bower

I'm currently attempting to use bower to install polymer's paper components but i'm getting errors.

I've tried:

- Running 'bower cache clear'
- Putting it in my bower.json and using 'bower update'

However, no matter what I try I end up with something along these lines (sometimes the element it fails on changes):

```
bower polymer-test-tools#^0.5            cached git://github.com/Polymer/polymer-test-tools.git#0.5.5
bower polymer-test-tools#^0.5          validate 0.5.5 against git://github.com/Polymer/polymer-test-tools.git#^0.5
bower core-drawer-panel#^0.5            ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/Polymer/core-drawer-panel.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Operation timed out

Stack trace:
Error: Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/Polymer/core-drawer-panel.git", exit code of #128
    at createError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/createError.js:4:15)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/cmd.js:102:21)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1176:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:476:12)
From previous event:
    at executeCmd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/cmd.js:61:22)
    at PThrottler._processEntry (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/p-throttler/index.js:89:25)
    at PThrottler._processQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/p-throttler/index.js:67:18)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PThrottler._onFulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/p-throttler/index.js:121:17)

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:82:17)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:110:22)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:40:20
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44

System info:
Bower version: 1.3.12
Node version: 0.12.0
OS: Darwin 14.3.0 x64
```

Bower seemed to work fine up until today.

Comment: Sounds like your machine can't connect to github: github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Operation timed out

Comment: NVM seems to have fixed itself today. I think it had something to do with them releasing the .8 preview.

Comment: It is probably because you don't have a public key registered with Github, so the `ssh://` was failing for you. Either change the dependencies for an `http / https` scheme, or add your public key to Github and make sure it's registered with your SSH agent.

Comment: Guys this problem was solved April 8th...

Answer (score 1):

Try running this:

```
$ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```